# Tcl question - how to list functions in a namespace

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I am trying to list all of the functions a namespace has in it (warning - I'm really new to Tcl, so I'll probably use the wrong words for parts of Tcl).  For example, I have a tcl shell someone compiled for me (if that's the right way to phrase it), and I know at least one function exists, let's call it

```
blah::do_something
```

I know in ruby there are ways to list all the functions in a module/namespace.  How would I find out what other functions are available in the `blah` namespace in Tcl?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You use `[info commands]` to query what commands are available, and you can scope it to a particular namespace by specifying a glob-style pattern.  For example:

```
% info commands ::blah::*
::blah::do_something
```

Comment: sorry it took so long to get mark this - it wouldn't let me do it right awawy and I forgot :^(

Answer (score 4):

Also: `namespace eval ::blah {info procs}`